# a callback function with time javascript

Tags: javascript

"need help !!"
Test 4
Write a function f4 that accepts a callback function, cb , as parameter and returns a function
that, no matter how often it’s called, it calls cb at most once every 300 milliseconds.
Example:
● const f = f4(cb); f();
---○ cb is called once without a delay.
 
-----Explanation:
-------■ f4 is called the first time, so cb has not yet been called in the last 
        300 milliseconds, so it’s called directly.

● const f = f4(cb); f(); [after 100 milliseconds] f(); [after 200 milliseconds] f();
---○ cb is called once directly, then once after 300 milliseconds.
 
-----Explanations:  
------■ The first call of f() calls cb directly
------■ The second call of f() happens before 300 milliseconds are elapsed
        since the last call of cb so it’s ignored and cb isn’t called.
------■ The third call of f() happens 300 milliseconds after the last time cb 
        has been called so cb is called again.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please remember that you're asking real people for help, and it's important to make sure that you take the time to [write a good question](/help/how-to-ask) so that people can understand what you're asking, what code you already have, and what you've already tried to solve your problem. Right now, your question is super hard to read and more likely than not to get downvoted or even closed for being unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this debounce function written by David Walsh.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

To let a function only be called once every 300 milliseconds, you can do this:

```
var fn = debounce(function(){
  //can only be called once every 300 ms
}, 300);
```

**See Also:**

https://davidwalsh.name/essential-javascript-functions

Comment: This doesn't seem to call the function immediately the first time.

Comment: @BassemJadoui No problem. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: please if u know about springboot and hibernate help me here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727072/how-to-fix-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-springboothibernate

Comment: @MarkMeyer If the immediate argument is `true`, then it will be called immediately the first time, i.e. `var fn = debounce(function(){}, 300, true);`.