# How to fix "Detached entity passed to persist" Springboot+Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

guys i've tried different methods proposed here or in an other websites to fix this error, i've fixed it before but in another case, but this one seems a complicated one. , an entity named department which have a oneToMany relation with it self , so the departement can have one or many subDepartments , and a department should have one and only one parent department.

Department Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENTS")
public class Department {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "dep_id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private long depId;
 private String depName;

 @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
 @JoinColumn(name = "supDep", referencedColumnName = "dep_Id")
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(value ={"departments","users"} , allowSetters = true)
 private Department supDep;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supDep", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(value ={"supDep","users"} , allowSetters = true)
 private List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>() ;

Constructors & getters &setters...
}
```

DepartmentRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department,Long> {
Department findByDepName(String name);
}
```

DepartmentService Interface :

```
public interface DepartmentService {
 Department add(Department department);
 Department update(Department department, Long id);
 void delete(long id);
 List<Department> findAll();
 Department findByName(String name);
 Department findById(Long id);
 User getChefDep(Long idDep);
}
```

DepartmentServiceImplement :

```
@Service(value = "departmentService")
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {
    ....
@Override
public Department add(Department department) {

    Department newDep = new Department();
    if(department.getDepId() != 0)
        newDep.setDepId(department.getDepId());
    newDep.setDepName(department.getDepName());
    newDep.setChefDep(department.getChefDep());
    newDep.setSupDep(department.getSupDep());
    newDep.setDepartments(department.getDepartments());
    newDep.setUsers(department.getUsers());
    return departmentRepository.save(department);
   }
   ...
```

}

DepartmentController ADD method :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*") 
@RequestMapping("/department/")
public class DepartmentController {
  ...
   @PostMapping("add")
   public Department add(@RequestBody Department department) { 
      return departmentService.add(department);
     }
...
}
```

anyway, when i add a new department with postman it works and the department is saved in DATABASE :

```
    {
    "depName": "marketing",
    "supDep": null,
    "departments": []
   }
```

and when i add a new department with a supDep that doesn't exist in DATABASE it works too and the both entities are saved in DATABASE :

```
{
  "depName": "Security",
  "supDep":
   {
      "depName": "IT",
      "supDep": null,
      "departments": [],
      "chefDep": 0,
   }
}
```

but when i add a new department passing supDep a department that does exist :

```
 {
   "depName": "sub-marketing",
   "supDep":
   {
     "depId": 1,
     "depName": "marketing"
   }
}
```

it throws this annoying error :

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-03-17T14:49:40.071+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "detached entity passed to persist: com.ats.remotetimemanager.Model.Department; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.ats.remotetimemanager.Model.Department",
"trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.ats.remotetimemanager.Model.Department; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.ats.remotetimemanager.Model.Department\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:319)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
```

Comment: I cannot see any chefDep property within your entity?

Comment: And please share your getter and setter codes because it is generally caused by wrong setter declarations

Comment: chefDep its a property that have Long type and without any relation just a property

Comment: Did you try using `CascadeType.MERGE` ?

Comment: thank u it worked now ♥♥♥

Comment: my error was when i put cascade.merge i try to save the child entity hoping that he save the parent one like cascade.All

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the getters & setters :

```
    public long getDepId() {
        return depId;
     }

    public void setDepId(long depId) {
        this.depId = depId;
     }

     public String getDepName() {
         return depName;
      }

      public void setDepName(String depName) {
          this.depName = depName;
       }

       public Department getSupDep() {
          return supDep;
        }

         public void setSupDep(Department supDep) {
            this.supDep = supDep;
          }

     public List<Department> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
      }

      public void setDepartments(List<Department> departments) {
         this.departments = departments;
       }

       public long getChefDep() {
          return chefDep;
       }

       public void setChefDep(long chefDep) {
           this.chefDep = chefDep;
        }

       public List<User> getUsers() {
           return users;
       }

       public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
           this.users = users;
        }

     @Override
       public String toString() {
        return "Department{" +
            "depId=" + depId +
            ", depName='" + depName + '\'' +
            ", supDep=" + supDep +
            ", departments=" + departments +
            ", chefDep=" + chefDep +
            '}';
   }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, this is not a solution.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, `Lombok` might help you get rid of the boilerplate code in Java.

Comment: @Uvuvwevwevwe yes this is not the solution, the real solution  is to set Cascade type to merge thats it

Comment: yes back that time i didn't know lombock xd, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to implement the method

```
@Override
public Department add(Department department) {

Department newDep;
if(department.getDepId() != 0) {
    Optional<Department> optional = departmentRepository.findById(id);
    if(optional.isPresent()) {
       newDep = optional.get();
    } else {
       newDep = new Department();
    }
} else {
   newDep = new Department();
}

newDep.setDepName(department.getDepName());
newDep.setChefDep(department.getChefDep());
newDep.setSupDep(department.getSupDep());
newDep.setDepartments(department.getDepartments());
newDep.setUsers(department.getUsers());
return departmentRepository.save(department);
```

}